# Async Pipe Shows loading template even after the Eventsource closed

Tags: angular, typescript, observable, server-sent-events, async-pipe

I'm trying to fix a problem with the Angular async pipe and event source from a Spring boot WebFlux. I want to show the "loading data" message till the API call is done. Once the API returns data, then displays the data. If the API does not return any data or the result is empty then, show a "no data found" message.

My Code works when the data is present. However, when there is no data returned from the API, it still shows the "loading data" message from template. Here is my code.

I use an event source in my service.ts file.

```
    loadData():Observable<Advertisement[]>{
return new Observable((observer: Observer<any>) => {
      const eventSource = new EventSource(
       'My API Call'
      );
      eventSource.onmessage = (event) => {
        this.zone.run(() => {
          const json = JSON.parse(event.data);
          this.adList.push(json);  
          observer.next(this.adList);
        });
      };
      eventSource.onerror = (error) => {
        observer.complete();
        eventSource.close();
      };
      return () => eventSource.close();
    });
}
```

My component.ts file

```
this.ads$ = this.businessService.loadData(); //inside ngOnInit
```

My Template HTML looks like below.

```
<div *ngIf="ads$ | async as adsList; else loading">
    <div *ngFor="let ad of adsList">
        {{ad.name}}
    </div>
    <div *ngIf="adsList.length===0">
        No Data Found
    </div>
</div>
<ng-template #loading>
    <div>Loading Advertisements .:.</div>
</ng-template>
```

Can anyone help me to solve this issue?

Edit: I was able to use the same logic successfully on Non-Array Objects. If it's an Object which I'm returning from the event source, this works. But Arrays fail.

Comment: What does this have to do with `spring-webflux` this is all angular code

Comment: The API is done in webflux. There is nothing other than that.

Comment: If there isnt an explicit webflux problem with webflux code then please remove the tag

Comment: @Toerktumlare removed it.

Comment: I assume that when there is no data returned then this.adList stays empty. Don't see how exactly (maybe you can debug / output to console.log) but that would explain why the predicate in the ngIf resolves to false, so the loading template is shown.

Comment: @johey Yes. this.adsList stays empty. 

this.ads$ = this.businessService.loadData().pipe(
      map((response) => {
        console.log(response.length);
        return response;
      })
    );

response.length in console prints zero.
I even tried to send the blank List from the eventSource.onerror to explicitly empty the value after the stream closed.

 eventSource.onerror = (error) => {
  observer.next(this.adList);
        observer.complete();
        eventSource.close();
      };
   
That too didn't help.

Answer (score 0):

Because empty array is falsy value in JS. You can use (ads$ | async).length >= 0.

Comment: That throws an error ERROR TypeError: Cannot read properties of null (reading 'length')

Comment: Values not on the list of falsy values in JavaScript are called truthy values and include the empty array [] or the empty object {}.   Seems like it is truthy. Not Falsy. Referred here https://medium.com/coding-in-simple-english/what-are-truthy-values-in-javascript-e037bdfa76f8#:~:text=Values%20not%20on%20the%20list,everything%20but%20the%20falsy%20values.

Comment: You can use ?. (ads$ | async)?.length. Yes, an empty array is falsy, so it will always the ng-template.

Comment: <div *ngIf="ads$ | async as adsList; else loading">
 <div *ngFor="let ad of adsList">
 
 I'm trying to change this
 
 to 
 
 <div *ngIf="(ads$ | async).length as adsList; else loading">
 <div *ngFor="let ad of adsList">
 
 This gives me an error *ngFor as adsList will hold a boolean value.
 Tried this below 
 <div *ngIf="(ads$ | async as adsList).length ; else loading">
 
 That gives another error   Parser Error: Missing expected ) at 
 
 What's the right syntax to execute this? Really struggling to organize this.